# How to conquer Twitter Cards

Tags: twitter

I have two posts coming from my Drupal site. Each has twitter meta tags configured. When I plug the URL into the compose box in Twitter, the first provides a card, but the image is a gray placeholder

[image]

The second brings up no card at all.

The tags for the first are:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@accidentalcoder" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Doppelganger Destroyer: A Drush Script" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Create a drush script to remove nodes based on a predictable criterion." />
<meta name="twitter:site:id" content="123456789" />
<meta name="twitter:creator:id" content="123456789" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@accidentalcoder" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://theaccidentalcoder.com/doppelganger-destroyer-drush-script" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://theaccidentalcoder.com/sites/default/files/2023-06/doppelganger_t_0.png" />
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="Doppelganger stick figures with one crossed out with a red X." />
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="400" />
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="400" />
```

And for the second:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@accidentalcoder" />
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Drupal 10 Sandbox in 10 Easy Steps" />
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Simple steps to creating a D10 instance using ddev." />
<meta name="twitter:site:id" content="123456789" />
<meta name="twitter:creator:id" content="123456789" />
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@accidentalcoder" />
<meta name="twitter:url" content="https://theaccidentalcoder.com/drupal-10-sandbox-10-easy-steps" />
<meta name="twitter:image" content="https://theaccidentalcoder.com/sites/default/files/2023-06/sandbox_t.png" />
<meta name="twitter:image:alt" content="A sandbox containing a blue umbrella with &#039;10&#039; on it" />
<meta name="twitter:image:height" content="400" />
<meta name="twitter:image:width" content="400" />
```

I have tried adding a cache busting query string to the end of each image URL. No change.